# How to figure out my departure gate at Dubai airport Terminal 3?

Tags: transit, short-connections, dxb, emirates, connecting-flights

I'm traveling from Lahore to Birmingham with a connection at Dubai airport and a waiting time of **1 hour 40 mins**. My boarding pass says I arrive at Terminal 3 and also depart from Terminal 3 for Birmingham. But it does not give me a gate number.

Is 1hr 40min enough time to board another plane? Do I need to do anything before boarding my connecting flight (i.e check in, go through Immigration)?

Also how can I figure which gate am I departing from Dubai Terminal 3?

Please note my connecting flight is also an Emirates flight.

Comment: You don't know and they don't know the gate until you arrive.  Don't worry, it's incredibly clear and easy.  You will find huge signs telling you your gate as soon as you get off the first plane.  You have plenty of time for the changeover, no problem at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks as though you are on a through ticket for which **1 hr 40 min is ample**. You will not pass Immigration but there is a Security check on arrival. Your departure gate may not be known at this time. Signage in Terminal 3 is excellent and you are very unlikely to get lost. You will just need to check the departure boards once there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So you think 1hr 40min would be enough? It's my first time going through Dubai just a bit worried about missing my flight.

Comment: @Skywalker DXB is quite large, but it's pretty straightforward to navigate. You should have little difficulty making the connection as long as you aren't stopping off at a bar for a few drinks (and note that public intoxication is considered _offensive_ in UAE) or killing too much time in duty free. If your inbound flight is late, ask for help making the connection from your Emirates crew.

Comment: It's plenty of time. No problem. dxb is HUGE but simple.  *Don't hesitate to ask*.  I personally just constantly ask staff (who are everywhere, every few feet) "Which way to gate xyz?" - I just can't be bothered thinking out which way to go or glancing up to read a sign!  It's the safest, simplest, most convenient airport on Earth, you'll have no problem at all.

Comment: The big thing on that flight is whether you land at a "real gate" (you walk up the stairs thing) or whether, annoyingly, you get stuck using a damned bus.  it's impossible to know which it will be.  Even if stuck with a damned bus, you still have plenty of time, no problem.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest hurdle in Dubai is that once you arrive, you have to go through a security check before you can enter the transit area; and this can take a good amount of time - once, it took me 30 minutes.

However the good news is the terminal itself is very easily navigable. Once you pass through the security checks and are in the main terminal - walk up to any reception desk and scan your boarding pass at the barcode reader.

The system will then give you direction to your gate and your estimated walking time.

Or you can simply look up at the large bank of monitors displaying flights and departure times.

If you are on a very tight connection - and your inbound flight is late, you may be received at the gate by airport personnel that will get you priority access through the security line.

If all else fails, and you miss your flight - luckily you are in one of the largest and busiest terminals in the world. Simply approach any person at a transfer desk. They will book you on the next flight, and if there is a large delay, offer you a voucher to grab something to eat.

I can tell you from personal experience - it is very easy - and very comfortable - to spend 8+ hours just roaming around T3.

Comment: I find the chaos of it all interesting - I just sometimes stand on one side (usually next to the waterfall elevators, there is a coffee place there in the back) and watch the flood of people. But yeah, the lounges are superb.